# What is the difference between the different package files?

Tags: ros, ros2, package.xml, colcon

[image: Rosanswers logo]

What is the difference between the [`package.xml` file](https://www.ros.org/reps/rep-0149.html), [`colcon.pkg` file](https://colcon.readthedocs.io/en/released/user/configuration.html#colcon-pkg-files), and [`.meta` file](https://colcon.readthedocs.io/en/released/user/configuration.html#meta-files)?

When is it appropriate to use each of them? Is it ever appropriate to have more than one such file for a project and, if so, when?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/333249/what-is-the-difference-between-the-different-package-files?/) by [DanRose](https://answers.ros.org/users/43942/danrose/) on ROS Answers with karma: 274 on 2019-09-17

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The `package.xml` is the ROS package manifest format ratified by REPs (different ones for each format version: [REP 127 format 1](https://www.ros.org/reps/rep-0127.html), [REP 140 format 2](https://www.ros.org/reps/rep-0140.html), [REP 149 format 3](https://www.ros.org/reps/rep-0149.html). Every ROS package should have one of those. When being released with `bloom` the information from this file are being used to build the Debian control / rule files.

A `colcon.pkg` ([docs](https://colcon.readthedocs.io/en/released/user/configuration.html#colcon-pkg-files)) file must be placed in the root of a package (could be a ROS package, a plain CMake project / Python package, or anything else supported by `colcon` via extensions). It allows to specify package specific arguments. You would choose that is adding a file to the sources is feasible and you want to alter / amend any kind of meta data as well as custom command line arguments. If a package already has a ROS manifest this file can still be used to add additional information, e.g. about scripts which should be sources in order to provide completion (see [ros2cli](https://github.com/ros2/ros2cli/blob/5dc4d9bfe14a2a62667977bfaa52b2288af6c2f3/ros2cli/colcon.pkg)).

`meta` files ([docs](https://colcon.readthedocs.io/en/released/user/configuration.html#meta-files)) allow you to provide meta data for a package without placing the file in the source. They are mapped to a specific package based on their name or relative / absolute path. The meta data can contain information like additional dependencies (commonly when the package doesn't have a `package.xml` file) or information about hooks. E.g. for `Gazebo` there  is a [.meta](https://github.com/colcon/colcon-metadata-repository/blob/4301f7737eec0a54723121c83f7409b6275a594c/Gazebo.meta) referencing its setup script so that it gets sourced automatically when you source the setup file in the workspace level. Another example are CMake flags for [FastRTPS](https://github.com/colcon/colcon-metadata-repository/blob/4301f7737eec0a54723121c83f7409b6275a594c/fastrtps.meta) to enable security by default.

---

Originally posted by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) with karma: 16276 on 2019-09-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2